# Is class can declared as type for a variable in Kotlyn

Tags: kotlin, class, oop, variables, types

```
class SmartTvDevice : SmartDevice() {
}

// The SmartHome class HAS-A smart TV device.
class SmartHome(val Device: SmartTvDevice) {

}
```

Hi I am learning Kotlyn. I have a question in above syntax (val device: SmartTvDevice). I am assuming SmartTvDevice is type declaration for the variable. I learned only these types (syntax,int,Boolean,Float.). what is SmartTvDevice type. Is class can be declared as type. Could you pleae let me know documentation that I can read related to it. Thank you.

Searching and reading kotlyn documentation.

Comment: In Java / Kotlin / ... languages there are primitive and complex data types. Those are your buzzwords. Int, Float, .. are primitive. Beside that EVERY class is not just a wrapper of functionalities. It is also a own datatype that is independent and stateful. So in your examplke your smartHome can only take SmartTvs and no other smart devices. Inheritence can open this up and make it more dynamic.